# Open excel(.xlsx) file in any editor, so it doesn't block it

Tags: java, excel, intellij-idea, sublimetext3

***Background:*** I have a project, where I collect some data and write it in excel file(.xlsx). My project runs automatically every X hours to collect, process and write data to excel. It works fine.

---

***Problem:*** Sometimes I want to open excel file to see if everything is allright. When I open excel file in MS Excel I can do everything I want, but while file is opened, java fails to write data in file with:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\path\to\file\reportFile.xlsx 
(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
```

Obviously MS Excel blocks file while file is opened.

---

***Question:*** How can I open excel file so, that it would not be blocked from writing into it in java? Is there any plugin or editor(not online) for doing this?

---

***PS*** I am also writing some data to text(.txt) files. There I am using *Sublime Text* editor for viewing and editing files on the fly without blocking them. I would have something similar for excel files, but didn't find any solution. If I open excel file in Sublime Text it shows me hex numbers. I have tried to find a plugin for *Sublime Text* editor or for *IntelliJ IDEA*, but without success.

Comment: If the file `xxx.xlsx` cannot be opened for writing, open it for reading and save it as `xxx-(checksum-old)-new,xlsx`.

Comment: You can open excel first, the open the file in _read only_ mode. A simpler trick is to copy the file elsewhere an then open the copied file.

Comment: Have you tried opening the workbook as read-only? Press Ctrl-O, select the file and click the right down error next to open and select open as copy or open read-only (dont't know the exact english labels, I am using german excel) Edit: In newer Excel you need to use the open file dialog, the built-in list of recently used files does not allow this option

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, For now I will go with @minus solution, but still open for other suggestions